# What type should I use to store values like "999999.99" in Cassandra?

Tags: datatypes, cassandra, decimal

I wanna add a price column to my table to be able to store values from `0.0` to `999999.99`. I tried `price DECIMAL(8,2)` but it seems it doesn't work. How can I store such a value?

I am also wondering to know if there would be any pre-post processing needed after that because I use NodeJS/TypeScript`in  backend that handles all numeric values using`number` type!

I also like to know if is it a better idea to use string type insted?

`EDIT`: For example if I try

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.test(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  price DECIMAL(8,2));
```

I get:

> SyntaxException: line 3:15 no viable alternative at input '(' (...
> TEXT PRIMARY KEY,  price DECIMAL

But the following works with no problems:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.test(
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  price INT);
```

Comment: This is a question for [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra) - See [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The CQL type `decimal` is a good choice for storing currency values. However, your syntax is incorrect which is why you were getting a `SyntaxException`.

You won't be able to specify the precision in CQL since the `decimal` type maps to a variable-precision Java decimal type.

Here is an example that shows how to declare a column as `decimal` in CQL:

```
CREATE TABLE decimals (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    price decimal
)
```

You will need to enforce the precision in your application instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of your Stackoverflow [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76442902/10410162). You could have asked for additional clarification in the original post itself.

You could so something like these variants as I had explained in my other answer,

**Decimal**:

```
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> create table sedecimal(i int primary key, j decimal);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> insert into sedecimal(i,j) values(1,1.23);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> insert into sedecimal(i,j) values(2,1.234);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> select * from sedecimal ;

 i | j
---+-------
 1 |  1.23
 2 | 1.234

(2 rows)
```

**Float**:

```
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> create table sefloat(i int primary key, j float);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> insert into sefloat(i,j) values(1,1.1);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> insert into sefloat(i,j) values(2,2.56);
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> select * from sefloat;

 i | j
---+------
 1 |  1.1
 2 | 2.56

(2 rows)
```

See [docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#native-types) for more info.